# How to concat arrays in JS in mutating way?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

What is the best way to concat arrays in mutating way in JS? My problem:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = a;
a = a.concat([4,5,6]) //<-- typical way of array concatenation in JS
console.log(a) //[1,2,3,4,5,6]
console.log(b) //[1,2,3] <-- I'd like it to be the same like the first array
```

I can use some loop of course, but I wonder if there is some faster and cleaner way to achieve it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`push` mutates an array, but it expects sequence of arguments, so we use `apply`:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = a
a.push.apply(a, [4,5,6])
console.log(a) //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(b) //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In ES6 you could use spread operator `...`:

```
a.push(...[4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: var a = [1,2,3];
a.push.call(a, 10, 20, 30);
console.log(a); // => [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]

Comment: Or simply: `a.push(4, 5, 6);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `push.apply` here to update `a` without creating a new variable:

```
a.push.apply(a, [4,5,6]);
```

Or perhaps the more easier to understand:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [4,5,6]);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qLg4dvq8/)**

In short [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls a function `push` with the first argument set as your `this` (object context), and the second argument an array. It's equivalent to `a.push(element1, ..., element10)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `push` can take a variable number of arguments, and will push all of them to the end of the array. You can then write:

```
a.push.apply(a, [1, 2, 3]);
```

As `apply` will transform an array of arguments into an argument list for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep "a" as a property so that it can be accessed by reference:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.a = [1,2,3]
var b = myObj;
myObj.a = myObj.a.concat([4,5,6])

console.log(myObj.a);
console.log(b.a);
```